# P/Invoke System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, marshalling

My code is raising an exception. I am using P/Invoke to call some C API from a .NET project.

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

It's a `void` function which takes as input a struct of primitives. I have several working API methods with several different structs (much more "complicated") that are working.

Setup:

- VS 17 2022
- C++ 20
- .NET Framework 4.7.2

It happens both in Debug and Release mode.

C/C++ side:

```
typedef struct
{
    float visibility; //[m] Visibility range
    float thickness;  //[m] Thickness of the fog layer
    // int placeholder;
} Fog;

/// @brief set fog data to be forwarded to the IG
/// @param fog \ref Fuze::Interfaces::Fog with fog data
/// @param regionId the id of the region to be updated
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SetFogData(const Fog* fog, int regionId);

///interface.cpp
#include "Interface.h"
#include <iostream>

void SetFogData(const Fog* fog, int regionId)
{
    std::cout << "\n\nForwarding fog data to plugins\n";
    std::cout << "Fog data: " << fog->thickness << " " << fog->visibility << std::endl;
}
```

C# side:

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Fuze
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Fog
    {
        public float Visibility; // [m] Visibility range
        public float Thickness;  // [m] Thickness of the fog
        // int placeholder;
    }
    static public class API
    {
        private const string dllPath = "Fuze_API.dll";

        [DllImport(dllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void SetFogData(Fog fog, int regionId);

    }
}

// main.cs

using static Fuze.API;

class FakeClientDotNet
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fuze.Fog fog = new Fuze.Fog();
        fog.Thickness = 50.0f;
        fog.Visibility = 250.0f;
        SetFogData(fog, 0);
        
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nCompleted\n");
    }
}
```

This code generates the error. If I uncomment the `int placeholder` field (in both structs), it starts working and the data provided via P/Invoke is correct. I have the same behavior with a struct made of an `enum` (with the `int` specifier) and an `int`, in which I have to add a third `int` member to not get the exception in the title.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in the code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires showing a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce the crash. See [ask] for more information. Until a [mre] is shown, it is unlikely that anyone will have an answer or an explanation.

Comment: Okay. I'll prepare a proper example to be reproduced in the next days. Thank you

Comment: If your C++ function takes a *pointer* to a Fog struct, shouldn't your C# declaration pass the struct by `ref` instead of by value?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik let me know if now the question is better explained. The code I provided should be enough to test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C function takes a `Fog*` (so, a pointer):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SetFogData(const Fog* fog, int regionId);
```

But your P/Invoke declaration takes a `Fog` by value:

```
public static extern void SetFogData(Fog fog, int regionId);
```

That's a struct, and it's cdecl, so it gets copied on the stack. And then  the native side tries to interpret that `fog` object as a pointer and stuff goes wrong. Or at least that's a guess, in reality it's our good old friend *undefined behaviour*.

If you want to pass a pointer, pass a reference and let the marshaller turn that into a pointer:

```
public static extern void SetFogData(ref Fog fog, int regionId);
```

And then, later:

```
SetFogData(ref fog, 0);
```

Comment: `[In] in Fog fog` maybe? Given that it's `const`

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working! My follow up question is: it's the 20th API with the 20th different struct I've defined and until now it has worked fine with everything. The only difference is that all the other structs are way bigger (minimum of five integers plus a bunch of other stuff). And in this case (without the `ref`) the fog pointer was pinting to a 0x0000000 address which is clearly incorrect. Why wasn't this happening with all the other structs?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, anything can happen.